# AVFoundation Import Warnings after XCODE 8 upgrade

Tags: avfoundation, warnings, ios10, xcode8

Obj C project; just updated to Xcode 8 and iOS/10. App seems to work fine, however, getting warnings --

"Missing submodule 'AVFoundation.AVSpeechSynthesis'" 
"Missing submodule 'AVFoundation.AVAudioSession'"

These messages appear on the #import statements for AVAudioSession & AVSpeechSynthesis.

Does anyone know what's going on with this?

TIA

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is now a warning, but deleting the `AVAudioSession` and `AVSpeechSynthesis` imports makes it go away. All you need is the umbrella header:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
// delete us
//#import <AVFoundation/AVSpeechSynthesis.h>
//#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h>
```

Comment: Did even think to try it but that did it.  Thx